# how to provide the ‘--output /dev/null’ option and argument to suppress output?

Tags: bash, shell

how to  provide the ‘`--output /dev/null`’ option and argument to suppress output?
So I input the a script the curl of a website and then how can I add `/dev/null` and get a return status.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress error messages and progress meter you can use the `--silent` option:

```
curl --silent http://yourwebsite.com --output /dev/null
```

or using shorthand options:

```
curl -s http://yourwebsite.com -o /dev/null
```